# is it possible to keep last table row unsorted while sorting using Ember.SortableMixin?

Tags: ember.js

I iterate over collection that uses `SortableMixin` with the help of `ArrayProxy`. One row (last one) is added automatically, ready to fill in. I'd like to exclude it from sorting so that it is fixed at the bottom. Now it is sorted with the rest of the records.

Is it possible to always keep unsaved row with item (`id= null`) last?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use `sortFunction`.

```
sortFunction: function(a, b) {
    // If either has a null ID, keep it at the end
    if (Em.get(a, 'id') === null) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (Em.get(b, 'id') === null) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Otherwise sort normally, for instance, by name
    return (Em.get(a, 'name') < Em.get(b, 'name') ? -1 : 1);
}
```